# Losing indexing and performance when using SUBSTRB

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, substring

My report is running really slow due to this paramter query because I think I lose the indexing when I use SUBSTRB

```
select distinct SUBSTRB(BLD_YEAR_PERIOD,1,4) as BLD_YEAR_PERIOD
from example.table
where SUBSTRB(BLD_YEAR_PERIOD,1,4) >= 2010
and SUBSTRB(BLD_YEAR_PERIOD,5,2) = 01
order by BLD_YEAR_PERIOD
```

any suggestions on another way to do this.

Comment: Compare the fast and slow query plans. Whats the difference? Yes SUBSTRB will stop using an index on `BLD_YEAR_PERIOD` _if one exists_. Also you have some implcit conversion there. You should compare to strings not numbers. Also this is equivalent to `BLD_YEAR_PERIOD= '201001'` which does not require the function.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are using the byte-wise substring function instead of the normal `SUBSTR` function?

Comment: You have commented that the datatype is number. Then why can't you just use this: `where BLD_YEAR_PERIOD = 201001`

Comment: Because I am using it as a parameter in SSRS to select multiple dates so I want every distinct date option that ends in 01

Comment: I only just noticed that the year filter is not an equality predicate. The function-based index may still help, but an important question here is, approximately what percentage of the rows in the table are usually returned by this query? If it's more than 5% of the table I usually expect Oracle to do a full scan anyway.

Comment: Also, you haven't answered my question about why you're using the byte-wise function.

Comment: forgive me but I don't know what a byte-wise function is.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, calling a function like `SUBSTRB` on a column will usually cause Oracle to avoid using an ordinary index on that column.

If your query is really representative and you are searching the column using the exact parameters given, you *may* find that a function-based index is used and might make the query more efficient, e.g.:

```
CREATE INDEX idx1 ON example.table (
  SUBSTRB(BLD_YEAR_PERIOD,1,4)
 ,SUBSTRB(BLD_YEAR_PERIOD,5,2));
```

A covering index *may* make it even more efficient, assuming the query you gave is the actual query being run

```
CREATE INDEX idx1 ON example.table (
  SUBSTRB(BLD_YEAR_PERIOD,1,4)
 ,SUBSTRB(BLD_YEAR_PERIOD,5,2)
 ,BLD_YEAR_PERIOD);
```

One thing I'd check is why the optimiser isn't already using a Fast Full Scan on your existing index on`BLD_YEAR_PERIOD` (assuming that's what you've got right now, and also assuming that's the only column you're referring to in your query).

Comment: if there is no existing indexing on the BLD_YEAR_PERIOD field does it matter that I'm using the SUBSTRB function as far as performance goes?

Comment: No, it doesn't matter. For a query like yours to run fast, the primary consideration is the *access methods* Oracle can use to quickly reduce the search space. If there is no index that can do this, its fastest method is a full table scan. In this case, your predicates become merely *filter predicates* and will have only a negligible impact on overall performance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your **s**earch **arg**uments are no longer sargable. When you have a comparison in the form:

```
where field = <something>
```

or

```
where field = func( <something> )
```

then the system has a static value to compare to the field. Being a static value, it does not change from one row to the next. If the field is indexed, it can quickly scan to where that value is or quickly determine if the value does not exist.

However, if the comparison is in the form:

```
where func( field ) = <something>
```

The result of the function relative to the field value cannot be known ahead of time. The field value of every row must be passed to the function so the comparison can be made. So, yes, even if the field is indexed, still a complete table scan must be made.

The trick is to rework the comparison so that no manipulation of the field takes place. In your case, that is easy enough. What you are looking for are all date values that occur in January of 2010. This can be expresses thusly:

```
where   BLD_YEAR_PERIOD >= date '2010-01-01' 
    and BLD_YEAR_PERIOD < date '2010-02-01'
```

If you are passing in a date argument and you want all the results that occurred during the month of that date, it could be something like this:

```
where   BLD_YEAR_PERIOD >= trunc( p_date, 'month' )
    and BLD_YEAR_PERIOD < add_month( trunc( p_date, 'month' ), 1 )
```

This makes sure the static date values start on the first day of the month and the first day of the next month. Now the index can be used.

Comment: Good advice and true, except for the fact that Oracle supports function-based indexes.

Comment: True, but you would have to create two indexes: one for the trunc and one for the add_month. And if other queries used other functions for this or other fields, you'd have to create an index for each of those. If it should work out that all your queries will use either the raw field value or the result of one function, then go for it. Still, it is always good to know how to write sargable queries.

Comment: I think you're assuming BLD_YEAR_PERIOD is a date. There is nothing in the OP's question that suggests that, and plenty to suggest it is a string, e.g. `'201001'` for Jan 2010.

Comment: Yes, I'm assuming that date data is stored as date datatype. Otherwise, OP has another flaw that must be worked out.

Comment: In thinking about it, that would be a good case for an function-based index using the conversion function from text to date. Then use *that* field in my answer.

Comment: The actual data type is a number and formatted like this 201001 or 201002,201003 201101,201102,201103 etc... I need to only pull in the ones that end in 01 so if i'm looking for 2010 I need to only pull in 201001 or if i'm looking for 2011 than I need 201101 and not 201103.

Comment: Generally, a field should be the same datatype as the attribute. That is, if an attribute is an integer value, define the field as integer (or number(x,0)). If the attribute is a date, the field should be a date. This helps both in domain definition and easy in querying. In your case, you can still use the values as they are, but that is luck. Never rely on luck.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by a field should be the same datatype as the attribute. can you elaborate on this?  and maybe show an example of how my code should change.

Comment: At the logical level, you have an entity with attributes. One such attribute will be "build period" and it is...what? The period of time the entity was being built? Whatever. What best represents the value of this attribute? A date? Then you "get physical" and create the table to contain the entities with fields to contain the attributes. The field is BLD_YEAR_PERIOD. What is the available datatype closest to that of the attribute? A date or datetime (depending on the DBMS).

Comment: so you're saying change the data type to a date? unfortunately I don't have control over the database structures so that is out of my control and getting them to change it isn't going to happen, but I get what you're saying.

Comment: @TommCatt, I like your idea about using a FBI to effectively convert the column to a date. It might even help with queries like this - which is effectively based on a date range ("all January records in 2010 or later").